# sort array by time format

Tags: sorting

The above code i want to display according to time(sort time in ascending)
Please help me.Thanks

Comment: Please add the sample dat

Comment: please add what you like to sort, with an example.

Comment: Please show us the data you are trying to sort, and how your function is giving unexpected results. What do you want to achieve, what does not work?

Comment: Your `return 0` statement is in the wrong place, this won't give a consistent comparison function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the time is a string, just sort it alphabetically.

```js
var newPages = [{time:"18:30",msg:"I'm fine"},{time:"09:13",msg:"How are you?"},{time:"10:30",msg:"Hi"}];

var s="";

newPages.sort(function(a,b){return a.time.localeCompare(b.time);});

for(var i=0;i<newPages.length;i++){
  s+=newPages[i].time+" - "+newPages[i].msg+"\n";
}
document.getElementById("out").textContent=s;
```

```html
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

Comment: I cannot understand your requirement 1). Sorting works by comparing a to b, not b with itself. Please provide sample data and a sample result, if you do not want other people to downvote you.

Comment: I was asking you for sample data so I can understand how you want to treat estimated time compared to scheduled time, however your sample only has one time column. My current answer already deals with that.